# C# to F# double to float implicit conversion

Tags: f#

I have the following C# function:

```
public (double? Average, int? Count) AverageQuotes(Candle.Intervals Interval, DateTime From, DateTime To)
```

and I get the data in F#:

```
let struct (average, count) = db.AverageQuotes(previous, time, time + timespan)
```

The problem is that Average leaves the C# as a double? and arrives in the F# as Nullable so there is a double -> float conversion happening somewhere.

How can I keep the result as a double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In F#, `float` and `double` are aliases for `System.Double`. The aliases for 32-bit doubles are `float32` and `single`. See [basic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/basic-types) or section 18.1 of the [specification (PDF)](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf)